# How to Create a Button to Upload documents to a document library (Sharepoint 2010)

Tags: file-upload, sharepoint-2010

Need to link via a button to the Upload.aspx page. I want the "upload document" page to open when I click a custom button (pic).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button(pic), and on click call the bellow function

```
NewItem2(event, "http://<Web>/sites/sitecollectionName/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={EC8746E1-77F4-4B60-B50D-9427E0C0BE57}&RootFolder=")
```

please change the guid with your document library guid.
This will open "upload document" page in popup where you can upload documents.